# How can I make informed decisions on Keogh investments?

Tags: united-states, investing, retirement

I am in my late twenties making enough to live quite comfortably. My company offers Keogh retirement plans, and mine has been active for about a year and a half. Currently, about a third of it is in VOO and the rest in VFFVX.

I am really only interested in the safer index funds, but my current strategy is to do a bit of Googling and choose to buy shares in something without being very targeted or deliberate. I think that I'm off to a decent start but I'm looking for ways to be better informed when I make those decisions.

For someone in a Keogh plan investing for a longer-term period, how can I find advice and information to make better-informed decisions? Being fairly green with investing and personal finance in general it can be difficult to know what to look for and where.

Comment: "What are some good..." questions are usually deemed off topic here, both since the answers are likely to be opinion ony and because the answers change frequently (and SE is intended to be a reasonably stable reference).  Restructuring this question as "how can I..." is more likely to be accepted and productive.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I'll rephrase accordingly.

Comment: How's it different from any other retirement plan? Keogh plans have basically the same rules on investments as 401(k) or IRA.

Comment: I included the fact that it's a Keogh for context on the long-term intentions but I suppose at its core I'm just looking for more info on how to choose ETFs and those sorts of investments, how to gauge performance, all that. I'm still fairly new to that realm so while I am continuing to pursue general knowledge, something more targeted could help.